# Using @RolesAllowed on Controller and getting "object is not an instance of declaring class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-security

I'm trying to use Method Security, so i put on dispatcher-servlet.xml (security.xml is on another context):

```xml
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
```

And put @RolesAllowed on Controller:

```java
@SessionAttributes({"sessionCompanyDetails"})
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class CompanyController extends BaseController {
  ...
```

I realized that when I use these annotations the Spring make a Proxy to Controller and because of that I get the error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because the Controller doesn't have an interface, so Spring creates a proxy but can't cast to Controller class.

Possible solutions are:

1. Interceptor: using MethodSecurityInterceptor and AccessDecisionManager
2. Using `<global-method-security proxy-target-class="true"/>` that activate CGLib proxy (proxy class is a subclass), so Spring can cast it.
3. Create an interface to Controller.
4. Using AspectJ.

I tested all solutions but the AspectJ. I'm using the CGLib solution for one project and for another I'm using Interceptor, both solutions works fine.